# How to best navigate a bad grade in senior year?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, europe, grades

I’m in my undergraduate senior year and by the looks of it I’ll be getting a failing grade in an elective math course. For reference I want to apply to a theoretical physics Masters degree, but in a field that is fairly unrelated to this course (think, say, group theory and  astrophysics). My other grades in all of my semesters are mostly “excellent" with the occasional “good”, and I have significant research experience, come September I can realistically even have 1-2 publication preprints. Presumably I will  also have a strong letter of recommendation.

My question Is, how can I minimise the damage by this failing grade?

Do I hand in my application while this semester is technically on-going, thereby hiding this grade? The usual deadlines are around March - April next year.

Do I try to give a brief explanation in my statement-of-purpose, even if I don’t have any particularly good reason for the failure ?

Comment: Is this for US grad study?

Comment: No, it’s for a European Masters degree.

Comment: It should not be a problem as you will do the master program in Europe. Unless you are going apply to the best institutions (eg ETHZ) it should be fine. The problem you should worry about is whether or not you are eligible for that master program.

Comment: ETHZ isn't my first choice, but I actually wanted to apply for the hell of it. Also, what do you mean about me being eligable or not?

Comment: Because some universities (and countries) will require your master program to be in the same field as the bachelor degree. I am not sure if it is possible to switch to physics.

Comment: My Bsc is in physics

Answer (score 1):

Since you are applying for theoretical physics, a failed Math may raise some concerns in Admission's Committees or potential Supervisors.  If you have "Excellent" in other Math courses at the same level, you should be fine, but if those are the courses where you only have "Good", it is more of an issue. You say that "you don't have any particularly good reason", but if it was simply that you didn't find the course interesting but didn't drop it in time, that could be worth saying.

Comment: What do you think about submitting my application before this semester is over, while my transcript doesn’t contain this grade?
What do you think about lying to admission by making up a reason for this, like saying the reason I failed is because I forgot/had to miss an exam? I think that paints a better picture and is not even that untrue.

Comment: Do not lie on the application!!!